# Shibboleth SP to PingIdentity idp Connectivity

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth, pingfederate

How to configure Shibboleth SP(Service provider) to connect to pingIdentity  IDP ?.

Actually already setup the Shibboleth SP(on window,iis7) and running properly and also worked well with an idp. Now I want  to  connect this Shibboleth SP with WGU(Western Governors University) idps which is a PingIdentity Idp. I didn't find any way how to connect Shibbleth Sp to  PingIdentity IDP.

Please provide the Step by Step process Or Any relevant link which help us.

Thanks,

Pradeep Kumar

Comment: .You have tagged this with asp.net, where does that fit in? Have you done any research on configuration of the Shibboleth SP? Is Shibboleth already running, and you're just trying to add an IdP? This is a poorly worded question, and does not meet the Stack Overflow standards

Answer (score 0):

Shibboleth and Ping are both implementations of SAML. So you don't need to treat them differently while configuring Ping as Identity Provider (IdP).
So the integration will work the same way if it was a shibboleth IdP. You will use Shibboleth SP's metadata and provide as input to the ping IdP. Check what attributes the IdP is releasing, usually the ping IdP's metadata file has the list. Decide how to map those attributes to your shibboleth SP's inputs. Then the ping IdP's metadata will be stored in shibboleth SP.
To  try it out first, you can download and install pingFederate following the documentation on their site, and then you configure it as an IdP. It will take your Shibboleth SP's metadata as input.
https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF70/Installing+PingFederate
This is the link to the installation steps and you can create an account and get the download zip